# Selector Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Hello iam learning jquery and JavaScript and i have a bunch of divs and span inside them, all this div has the same class, and also the span all of them has the same class what i want is when i do mouse over on a div, change the color of the letters with the tag span inside that div. ill let you how i structured my cod and my jquery function. i would like to know how i can use selector to achieve this.

this is the jsFiddle:

```
$(".wrap-faq").on("mouseover", hoverFaq);

    function hoverFaq(){
        $(".wrap-faq .faq .txt-preg-faq").css("color", "white")
        $(this).addClass("over");
    }

$(".wrap-faq").on("mouseleave", unHoverFaq);

    function unHoverFaq(){
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/jz73b/

Comment: Your code seems to do what you want, where's the issue?

Comment: This question sounds a bit fishy to me...

Comment: the issue is that i dont want all of them to be white, just the one i do mouse over, i dont want all the spans to get white :/

Comment: seems like just using css would be much more efficient for something like this.  Also seems like you could use better dom structure if you had to do it with jQuery

Comment: yeah, but im working ins omeone else strucutre :/ thats why is it so unorganized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want a simple CSS hover:

```
.faq {
    color: black;
}
.faq:hover {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
}
```

This http://jsfiddle.net/saYFz/ is what you want?

Comment: @Jhonnatan Gonzalez Rod I agree, even though you are just learning jquery, it's also a valuable lesson to learn when NOT to use jquery ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code will add a CSS class to div when you hover over it:

```
$(".wrap-faq").on("hover",
    function(){
        // on over, add class "over"
        $(this).addClass("over");
    },
    function(){
        // on out, remove class
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
);
```

Use CSS for the span manipulation. Like:

```
.over span {color:red;}
```

Edit: If you want to process the hover only at span, you can simply modify the selector to:

```
$(".wrap-faq span")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is more what you're wanting:

http://jsfiddle.net/jz73b/1/

```
$(".contents-faq").on("mouseover", '.wrap-faq', function() {
    $(".wrap-faq .faq .txt-preg-faq").css("color", "white")
    $(this).addClass("over");
}).on("mouseleave", '.wrap-faq', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your `hoverFaq` function:

```
$(this).find('span').css('color', 'white');
```

Here you have it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jz73b/2/